# Error: dispatch is not a function, connecting injectStripe and mapDispatchToProps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, stripe-payments

I'm having trouble wiring up `mapStateToProps` so that the action gets appropriately called:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    createPayment: (token, email) => dispatch(createPaymentForToken(token, email)),
  };
};

const injectedCheckoutForm = injectStripe(CheckoutForm);
export default connect(mapDispatchToProps)(injectedCheckoutForm);
```

When I call `this.props.createPayment(token, email)`, I get the following error:

> index.js:130 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: dispatch is not a function

**Edit:** My action seems to be getting called but not my saga listening for the `CREATE_PAYMENT` action

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First parameter for [`connect`](https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect#overview) is [`mapStateToProps`](https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect#mapstatetoprops-state-ownprops-object) with the second being [`mapDispatchToProps`](https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect#mapdispatchtoprops-object-dispatch-ownprops-object). Instead try `connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)`.

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    createPayment: (token, email) => dispatch(createPaymentForToken(token, email)),
  };
};

const injectedCheckoutForm = injectStripe(CheckoutForm);
export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(injectedCheckoutForm);
```

Comment: Thanks Dom, easy to overlook that. Worked like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: Sure thing, let me know if there's anything else you need!

Comment: Please help me sir, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67180197/how-to-pass-props-data-from-render-to-handlesubmit-function-in-redux